# minimal oblique rectangle to sample wallpaper

Tags: tiling

From a rectangular wallpaper pattern with periods $(w,0)$ and $(0,h)$, you must cut a rectangle with aspect ratio $m$, to include every part of the pattern-unit; in other words, you must cover the (flat) torus.  You may rotate this sample-piece at any angle relative to the pattern.  How do you choose the rotation to allow the smallest such rectangle?

A sub-problem is: for a given rotation angle, what is the smallest $m:1$ rectangle that covers?

**Partial answer**, 2019 Feb 13. I think it necessary and sufficient that, for each point $(x,y)$ on the boundary of the (scaled and rotated) ‘sample’ rectangle, there exist integers $j,k$, not both zero, such that $(x+jw,y+kh)$ is within the (closed) rectangle.

The solution, then, will be to minimize (over rotation) the maximum (over the set of boundary points) of the minimum (over $j,k$) of a family of trig functions which express the minimum scale factor.

Comment: It seems the edit has turned the question into a different question?

Comment: @joriki The is the question I wanted to ask; if you think that's a different question, you confirm that the edit was necessary!