# Rotated rectangle with dimensions $c \times d$ inscribed in a rectangle with dimensions $a \times b$. How to express $d$ knowing $a,b,c$?

Tags: angle, rectangles

What we know: length of $a$, $b$, $c$

$a$ and $b$ are the sides of the large rectangle

what I need to find:
length of $d$ or just one angle (yellow color)
[image]

I found some solution on the internet with a similar problem, but damn is so hard to understand for me
http://people.missouristate.edu/lesreid/POW10.html

I believe that is the way to calculate "4 collision places" in a more simple way

Comment: Are $a$ and $b$ the side lengths of the large rectangle, or the distance from one corner of the large rectangle to a corner of the small rectangle?

Comment: are sides of the large rectangles. Edited on the main post

Comment: The linear system $$c\sin \theta+d\cos\theta=a\\d\sin\theta+c\cos\theta=b$$ has a compatible solution if $\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta=1$ or $$\begin{vmatrix}a&d\\b&c\end{vmatrix}^2+\begin{vmatrix}c&a\\d&b\end{vmatrix}^2=\begin{vmatrix}c&d\\d&c\end{vmatrix}^2.$$ This is a quartic equation in $d$.

Comment: @IAmAGuest I find back the same expression as yours. Please transform your excellent comment into a solution...

Comment: @JeanMarie: mh, I cannot edit the comment anymore to copy. It is enough that you pointed at it in your answer, thanks.

Comment: thanks @IAmAGuest! Very clean solution! Just need few more hours to understand it more :)

Comment: An answer using Newton's method to a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3470276).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Let $\alpha$ be the angle with interrogation mark (that is found back in each of the NE, NW, SE, SW similar right triangles), you have the 2 following relationships between quantities $a,b,c,d,\alpha$:

$$\begin{cases} d \cos \alpha + c \sin \alpha &=& a \\ c \cos \alpha + d \sin \alpha &=& b\end{cases} \tag{1}$$

Said otherwise, and using the idea given by IAmAGuest in his comments (thanks to him), (1) can be considered as a linear system

$$\begin{cases}d x +  c y &=& a \\ c x + d y &=& b\end{cases} \ \text{with} \  x:=\cos \alpha, y:=\sin \alpha\tag{1a}$$

The solutions of system (1a) are expressible in the following way (Cramer formulas):

$$x=\dfrac{\begin{vmatrix}a&d\\b&c\end{vmatrix}}{\begin{vmatrix}c&d\\d&c\end{vmatrix}}=\dfrac{ac-bd}{c^2-d^2}, \ \ \ y=\dfrac{\begin{vmatrix}c&a\\d&b\end{vmatrix}}{\begin{vmatrix}c&d\\d&c\end{vmatrix}}=\dfrac{cb-ad}{c^2-d^2},\tag{1b}$$

Constraint $x^2+y^2=1$ gives rise to the following relationship:

$$(ac-bd)^2+(cb-da)^2=(c^2-d^2)^2\tag{1c}$$

As a consequence, $d$ is "a"/"the" real positive solution of the 4th degree equation in variable $d$:

$$d^4-(a^2+b^2+2c^2)d^2+4(abc)d-(a^2+b^2-c^2)c^2=0\tag{1d}$$

Taking the numerical values $a=4,b=3,c=1$ considered in the (complicated) reference you gave, one obtains the same real positive root as theirs : $d\approx 4.0851$.

**Remark:** An alternative (longer) method is worth mentionning. It amounts to transform (1) into polynomial expressions using the classical rationalization formulas:

$$\begin{cases}\cos \alpha &=& \frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2} \\ \sin \alpha &=& \frac{2t}{1+t^2}\end{cases} \ \ \ \text{where} \ \ \ t:=\tan \frac{\alpha}{2}\tag{2}$$

Plugging expressions (2) into (1) generates 2 quadratic equations in variable $t$:

$$\begin{cases}2ct + d(1-t^2) &=& a(1+t^2) \\ c(1-t^2)+ 2dt&=& b(1+t^2) \end{cases} \ \iff \ \begin{cases}(a+d)t^2-2ct +(a-d)&=&0\\ (b+c)t^2-2dt+(b-c)&=& 0 \end{cases}\tag{3}$$

that must share a common root. This can be expressed by eliminating the $t^2$ term: indeed multiplying (3a) by $(b+c)$ and (3b) by $(a+d)$ and subtracting allows to express $t$ as a function of $a,b,c,d$. Plugging this expression into (3a) for example gives back (1d) .

If you are acustomed to "resultants" (see for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2537941)), expressing that the two polynomials in (3) share a common root can be done by setting the following resultant to zero:

$$\begin{vmatrix}a+d&-2c&a-d&0\\0&a+d&-2c&a-d\\b+c&-2d&b-c&0\\0&b+c&-2d&b-c\\\end{vmatrix}=0. \tag{4}$$

Expanding (4) gives back (1d), once more.

**Edit 1:** I just found [using the formula searching engine approach0.xyz] [this reference](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h482815p2705285) with the same numerical approximation.

**Edit 2:**: Applying Descartes' rule of signs to (1d) where the coefficients between parentheses are all $>0$, one can say that equation (1d) has at least $1$ positive root.

Comment: Oh yea, the main problem is that I don't have the angles for the little rectangle.

Are you sure it isn't unique? It is a maximum rectangle that use "c" length as one of the sides of the little rectangle

Comment: Do you still get a rectangle if you keep $a,b,c$, but change $\alpha$? (Assuming the whole figure keeps $180^\circ$ rotation symmetry, and the corners of the small rectangle lie on the large rectangle's sides.) My gut says you don't.

Comment: you're right, but why do you want to change α?
Unfortunately in this case I don't know what is α. The main task is to create rotated rectangle in the big rectangle using only a,b,c

Comment: oh dude, thanks for so detailed answer!

Comment: The inverse situation is handled in this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/60718)

Comment: A cousin question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/61005) as well.

Answer (score 1):

It is a heavy expression found by Mathematica. L&W used in place of (a&b), that I did not further simplify.

[image]

Using Geogebra

$$ \text{input}(L,W, y)= (6.33,3,1.05),\text {output is}(x=6.32)$$
that is only a bit less than L.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see the use that can be made of these huge and **blurred** expressions...